# bios/motherboard doesn't recognize/see all dimms. 2 out of 3 show in bios

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios

OK

1. Asrock x58 extreme motherboard 1366
2. ocz 6gb ddr3 kit OCZ3G1600LV6GK
3. intel core i7 920
4. win7 64bit pro

i plug it all together, i get 4gb in bios...

all dims are seated properly, in proper slots. for the asrock its a1,b1,c1.

bios shows a1,b1 jsut fine, doesn't show c1.

boot windows, 4gb shows

load cpuz, it shows all 3 dimms, reads xmp settings off all 3.

any thoughts why that 3rd dim isn't showing?

if i rotate the dims around or boot with just 1 at a time they all work fine....

Comment: i hope it is understood, but the kit is 3 dimms of 2gb each

Comment: Have you modified any RAM settings in the BIOS? At least for the Asus P6T it states support only up to 1333MHz DDR3 w/o OC, and if you set it to more it might refuse seeing all RAM modules. Also, P6T is listed as a 6-DIMM MB: have you followed the color codes for triple-channel? (just to be sure, I believe you did)

Comment: a wild idea, but... what is the wattage of your PSU?

Comment: psu is 650, healthy, really nice quality.

the ram settings are always default when i boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok thanks to hointa from: [ocz forum](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?p=464830)

i was able to get it working...

1. I bought an Asus P6T - it doesn't use the Foxconn socket, it has a loates brand socket. I'm not 100% sure this is contributing as I bent some pins on the Asrock and didn't try it again.
2. i **REALLY** had to torque the heatsink down tight =\ what really bugs me though, is that scythe says in the manual don't overdo it bc you might break the mobo...

well i'm seeing all 6gb now and i overclocked the i7 920 to 4.2ghz with the scythe mugen 2 =] it is running at 68-70 on 100% load prime95 on the asus p6t

all is well!

thank you quack and chronos for your help and ideas.

Comment: good job, glad you got it working.

Comment: thank you =] 

i bought the CPU used and the seller claims he tested it to 4.4 @ 1.42v on a promiltech magawhatever its called, the big $70 cooler.

my scythe, which was a pain in the arse, was only $40 and is withing 200mhz and about 20 degrees centigrade cooler than the seller's numbers! =]

Answer (score 2):

You are running 64-bit Windows, right?  32-bit Windows won't show more than 4GB.

If you are using 64-bit Windows, double-check these troubleshooting steps:

- Try each DIMM, one at a time, in one slot.  Boot, check that the motherboard seems OK, maybe run Memtest86+.  If it works, the DIMM is pronounced good, repeat with next DIMM.
- Try one good DIMM, in one slot at a time.  Boot, check mobo, maybe run Memtest86+.  If it works, the slot is pronounced good, repeat with next slot.

If all DIMMs are good (by themselves) and all SLOTS are good (by themselves) then your trouble is the motherboard.  Is it supposed to operate 6gb total?  Is it running the latest BIOS version?  Check the manual and specs.  Check BIOS settings.  If supported, try underclocking the memory.

If nothing else works, consider contacting the retailer for another motherboard -- it's possible you've gotten a wonky one.

Comment: Yes, bios is 1.60.
Yes Win7 64bit.
Yes, 3 sticks of 2gb each.

Each stick is good in slot a1, so I will try to test each slot as per your comment. 

I think my problem might be something along these lines:
http://www.hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1463560

Only I don't have P55. I have a 1366, X58

Comment: bizarre.  in that case an incorrectly-installed chipset cooler was the root cause.  if you've built this computer yourself, triple-check that __everything__ on that motherboard is installed correctly.

Comment: OK - In the process of checking each slot, and making sure I didn't torque the cooler down too tight I somehow got it to display just 1 dimm. 

Guess which one? C1. The one that refused to show, is reading the dimm slot perfectly. 

I have all 3 stickins in and just 2gb is being recognized. =\

I'm very upset with 1366 socket and layout types. 

I'm not sure who to blame, the cooler design, the motherboard or the ram or the cpu... 

I have built it myself and this isn't my first either. Le Sigh.

Comment: hrm.  you sure you didn't have any tensioning springs laying around that you forgot to install?  :)  at this point, i'd seriously consider calling the retailer for an RMA and exchange.

Comment: <p>yes i'm quite sure. i'm using the scythe mugen 2. </p>

<p>
i'm going to microcenter tonight and getting as many x58 boards as i can to try and experiment and see. </p>

<p>
newegg wants me to ship the asrock board back to them, at my expense, and they can provide another board for me. i may do that but i'm not sure =\</p>

Comment: OK _ I bought an Asus P6T. Setup the system. SAME exact problem. 3 sticks in, only 2 detected. Super lame. --- I'm almost ready to put the blame on the CPU now.